# Set div innerhtml to source that contains table

Tags: internet-explorer-8, innerhtml

I thought what I was trying to do is quite simple, but apparently nothing related to IE is ever simple.

I'm using this with Javascript and ajax -

```
document.getElementById("calender").innerText=mypostrequest.responseText
```

It works fine in Firefox and IE7, but not IE8. I suspect it's because the text contains a table, since I have tested it with other text. I can't replace the table. Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: Can you show some code? What error messages do you get?

Comment: Sorry meant I'm using innerHTML, not innerText

Comment: Can you show some of the code that you are trying to insert?

Comment: I don't get any errors. This is the line I'm having a problem with -
document.getElementById("calender").innerHTML=mypostrequest.responseText

'calender' is a div. mypostrequest.responseText contains a table. from what I've read so far, that's where the problem comes in.

Comment: doesn't IE8 ship with a javascript console? I'd use that to debug my javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
document.getElementById("calender").innerHTML=mypostrequest.responseText
```

Comment: Sorry meant to say that earlier. Tried it as well and doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Switched to jQuery

```
( $('#calender').html(mypostrequest.responseText) )
```

It works now.